# google play console - zip path traversal error

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-console, android-security, android-securityexception

I've created a simple unity game and i don't use any kind of file or zip file structure in my game.
but google play notice this error:
Zip Path Traversal
Your app contains an unsafe unzipping pattern that may lead to a Path Traversal vulnerability. Please see this Google Help Center article to learn how to fix the issue.

it's really confused me
I really appriciate you to help me fix it??
Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

This likely means you have a file in the APK or AAB that has a path that starts with "../" (= parent directory), which if not processed properly, can lead to security issues.

You can maybe look at the file you uploaded with a zip program to see which file that is, that may help identify what's wrong.